# Hacker-earth trouble File Name should be main.java

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, filenames

```
solution/oom.Main.java:176: error: class Main is public, should be declared in a file named Main.java
public class Main {
       ^
1 error
```

Can someone tell me what should be the class name?

I am already using this :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: Your name of the public class and Java file should be the same.

Comment: Solved ! The class name should be TestClass Instead of Main.

Comment: Yes, but in hacker-earth platform, how do I know what should be the fileName ?

Comment: So I just opened a default template and copied !

Comment: Just don't use **public** access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

The name of a java file containing a public class should be the same as the class name, with a `.java` extension. Here, your class is called `Main`, but your file is called `oom.Main.java` instead of `Main.java`.

Answer (score 1):

Rename file `oom.Main.java` to `Main.java`
That's the reason of error `Main is public, should be declared in a file named Main.java`